# Vue cli 4.51 trouble building after deleting and reinstalling node_modules

Tags: webpack, vue-cli-3

I have a Vue CLI 3 project that used to build and serve just fine.

After deleing and reinstalling my node_modules folder. Now, when i run *npm run serve*, I get the following

```
Error loading C:\code\parkadminfrontend\vue.config.js:
 ERROR  ValidationError: Invalid options object. Ignore Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options should be one of these:
   object { resourceRegExp, contextRegExp? } | object { checkResource }
   Details:
    * options misses the property 'resourceRegExp'. Should be:
      RegExp
      -> A RegExp to test the request against.
    * options misses the property 'checkResource'. Should be:
      function
      -> A filter function for resource and context.
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Ignore Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options should be one of these:
   object { resourceRegExp, contextRegExp? } | object { checkResource }
   Details:
    * options misses the property 'resourceRegExp'. Should be:
      RegExp
      -> A RegExp to test the request against.
    * options misses the property 'checkResource'. Should be:
      function
      -> A filter function for resource and context.
    at validate (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:105:11)
    at C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\create-schema-validation.js:16:17
    at new IgnorePlugin (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\IgnorePlugin.js:28:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\vue.config.js:19:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at exports.loadModule (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\module.js:79:14)
    at Service.loadUserOptions (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:330:22)
    at Service.init (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:70:30)
    at Service.run (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:215:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\parkadminfrontend\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:36:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

Here is my **vue.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
      disableHostCheck: true,
      port: 8080,
      public: '0.0.0.0:8080'
  },

  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],

  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ]
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('assets')  
  },

  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'da',
      fallbackLocale: 'da',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: true
    }
  }
}
```

I think there is a mismatch in webpack versions, but i am not sure how to solve this. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I found that somehow my webpack version was upgraded to 5.53.0, which had breaking changes for my project. Rolling back to webpack@4.44.2 solved my problem.

Comment: I ran accoss same error when start antd-pro-vue, and found the webpack version is 5.61.0 under node_modules folder,  then I downgraded webpack to 4.46.0, problem solved.